# From List, return a NEW List of each original list's property?

Tags: c#, list, class

Say, my Dog class have another class in it, Flea.

```
class Dog
{
   public Flea flea;
}
```

Now, if I have a list of Dogs : `List<Dogs> manyDogs`
How can I turned that list into a `List<Flea> fleaInEachDogs`?

Currently I will do it like this :

```
List<Flea> fleaInEachDogs = new List<Flea>();
foreach(Dog d in manyDogs)
{
    fleaInEachDogs.Add(d.flea);
}
```

But I think a more convenience aggregate method is surely available for all `List` class. Is there exist any?

Comment: Is your `flea` property really `private`?

Comment: Is your `flea` property really just a field?

Comment: I'm sorry! It's public not private. Question edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `Select` extension to be more concise about it, though there's nothing like a "pluck" method to get properties by name (seeing as that would require reflection):

```
var fleaInEachDogs = manyDogs.Select(dog => dog.flea);
```

(Use `ToList()` on that `IEnumerable` to get a list exactly like your original code.)

Comment: @JohanLarsson: Assuming. :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Neither would have the original code. The [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123720/from-list-return-a-new-list-of-each-original-lists-property/16123736?noredirect=1#comment23029990_16123736) was in reference to "Assuming `flea` is private."

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to be more explicit about that in the actual answer.

Comment: Sorry, the question is mistyped. It's public not private and the .Select works nicely. Thanks.